# std::function as callback, is unregistration possible?

Tags: c++, c++11

The question is strictly about `std::function` and not `boost::function`. See the *Update* section at the bottom of this question for more details, especially the part about it not being possible to compare non-empty `std::function` objects per the C++11 standard.

---

The C++11 `std::function` class template is great for maintaining a collection of callbacks. One can store them in a `vector`, for example and invoke them when need be. However, maintaining these objects and allowing for unregistration seems to be impossible.

Let me be specific, imagine this class:

```
class Invoker
{
public:
  void Register(std::function<void()> f);
  void Unregister(std::function<void()> f);

  void InvokeAll();

private:
  // Some container that holds the function objects passed to Register()
};
```

Sample usage scenario:

```
void foo()
{
}

int main()
{
  std::function<void()> f1{foo};
  std::function<void()> f2{[] {std::cout << "Hello\n";} };

  Invoker inv;

  // The easy part

  // Register callbacks
  inv.Register(f1);
  inv.Register(f2);

  // Invoke them
  inv.InvokeAll();

  // The seemingly impossible part. How can Unregister() be implemented to actually
  // locate the correct object to unregister (i.e., remove from its container)?
  inv.Unregister(f2);
  inv.Unregister(f1);
}
```

It is fairly clear how the `Register()` function can be implemented. However, how would one go about implementing `Unregister()`. Let's say that the container that holds the function objects is `vector<std::function<void()>>` . How would you find a particular function object that is passed to the `Unregister()` call? `std::function` does supply an overloaded `operator==`, but that only tests for an empty function object (i.e., it cannot be used to compare two non-empty function objects to see if they both refer to the same actual *invocation*).

I would appreciate any ideas.

**Update:**

Ideas so far mainly consist of the addition of a cookie to be associated with each `std::function` object that can be used to unregister it. I was hoping for something that is not exogenous to the `std::function` object itself. Also, there seems to be much confusion between `std::function` and `boost::function`. The question is strictly about `std::function` objects, and **not** `boost::function` objects.

Also, you cannot compare two non-empty `std::function` objects for equality. They will always compare non-equal per the standard. So, links in the comments to solutions that do just that (and use `boost::function` objects to boot) are patently wrong in the context of this question.

Comment: You could do what MS did with connection points: Return a cookie (index into your vector) that the caller provides to deregistration.

Comment: I often store interface pointers as callbacks and put them in a set. Then I can access by value to unregister.

Comment: @WhozCraig Boost does that for one of their classes also.

Comment: [Storing boost::function objects in a container, UnregisterCallback](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13095974/1762344), [Why is std::function not equality comparable?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13105074/1762344)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing boost::function objects in a container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094720/storing-boostfunction-objects-in-a-container)

Comment: You may consider also Boost.Signals2.

Comment: In your example it sounds like `boost::signals` is what you require. In the past I have used a `std::map` you could always have the `register` function accept a key along with the callback, whcih can also be supplied when calling `unregister`.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't recommend using the index in the vector as a cookie.  If you unregister the first callback, all cookies will be invalidated!

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk's answer on the linked question is what you want; it works equally with `std::function` as with `boost::function`.

Comment: @AndréCaron Certainly. The index was merely an example of what a cookie *could* be. I'd likely use a std::list<> and an iterator for the cookie, or something similar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you can't test for element identity in the container, it's probably best to use a container (such as `std::list`) whose iterators do not invalidate when the container is modified, and return iterators back to registering callers that can be used to unregister.

If you really want to use `vector` (or `deque`), you could return the integral index into the vector/deque when the callback is added.  This strategy would naturally require you to make sure indexes are usable in this fashion to identify the function's position in the sequence.  If callbacks and/or unregistration is rare, this could simply mean not reusing spots.  Or, you could implement a free list to reuse empty slots.  Or, only reclaim empty slots from the ends of the sequence and maintain a base index offset that is increased when slots are reclaimed off the beginning.

If your callback access pattern doesn't require random access traversal, storing the callbacks in a `std::list` and using raw iterators to unregister seems simplest to me.

Comment: After being a C++ programmer for 17 years, I finally know a reason to use a `std::list` by itself!

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for this.

Store the callbacks as `std::weak_ptr<std::function<void(argtype1, argtype1)>>`.  Then the caller is responsible for keeping the corresponding `std::shared_ptr` alive, and all the caller has to do to unregister the callback is destroy all active `std::shared_ptr`s to the callback function.

When invoking callbacks, the code has to be careful to check for lock failures on the `std::weak_ptr<>`s it is using.  When it runs across these it can remove them from its container of registered callbacks.

Note that this does not give complete thread safety, as the callback invoker can lock the `std::weak_ptr` and make a temporarily newly active `std::shared_ptr` of the callback function that can stay alive after the caller's `std::shared_ptr` goes out of scope.